# Angular flex-layout next element from the new line

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I have such layout:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxLayoutGap="10px">
    <mat-form-field fxFlex="30">
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="datePickerFrom" placeholder="Choose a date">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datePickerFrom"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #datePickerFrom></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field fxFlex="30">
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="datePickerTo" placeholder="Choose a date">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datePickerTo"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #datePickerTo></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>

    // want new line here

    <mat-form-field fxFlex="41">
        <input matInput placeholder="Name">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field fxFlex="30">
      <input matInput placeholder="Surename">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field fxFlex="20">
      <mat-select placeholder="Details">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let d of details" [value]="d.value">
            {{ d.viewValue }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

[image]

I want last three `mat-form-field` elements always started on a new column.

How would you do that using flex-layout without changing the html layout?

Currrently I achieve that by setting `fxFlex=41` on the input but - this way the new line gets started, but it won't work if I set the `fxFlex` less than `41` or if I set the `fxFlex` on datepickers less then `30`.

Comment: Can you clarify how you envision the layout?  Your container declares a row layout, but you want the last 3 form-fields to be in columns? E.g. you want 3 columns side by side or you want them stacked in a column? Perhaps a simple image of what you're trying to accomplish would help a lot.

Comment: @Narm just updated the question

Comment: When you say "without changing the html layout" do you mean absolutely no additional HTML can be added/used? The layout you have shown would very easily be accomplished if you would wrap the grouped form fields in there own row.

Comment: @Narm so are you saying that there is no way to achieve that without adding an additional html?

Answer (score 0):

use this instead of your code

```
<div fxLayout="row">
<mat-form-field fxFlex="30">
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="datePickerFrom" placeholder="Choose a date">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datePickerFrom"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #datePickerFrom></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field fxFlex="30">
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="datePickerTo" placeholder="Choose a date">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datePickerTo"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #datePickerTo></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div fxLayout="row">
<mat-form-field fxFlex="41">
        <input matInput placeholder="Name">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field fxFlex="30">
      <input matInput placeholder="Surename">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field fxFlex="20">
      <mat-select placeholder="Details">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let d of details" [value]="d.value">
            {{ d.viewValue }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```